# Android: Access activity from handler

Tags: android

I have the following handler:

```
public class SiteListener implements OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call the following:

```
myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.site_info, siteInfoFragment)
            .commit();
```

How do I gain access to the activity from SiteListener? Is there a way using the `adapterView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `FragmentActivity` with `view` to get the instance of `FragmentActivity`.

```
FragmentActivity activity = ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext());
activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.site_info, siteInfoFragment)
            .commit();
```

Comment: Is context guaranteed to be an activity?

Comment: In your case it would be FragmentActivity. As you require FragmentActivity instance to call `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Yes `((FragmentActivity)view.getContext())` would give you the instance FragmentActivity the view is attached to.

Answer (score 3):

Pass a reference to the activity to the `SiteListener` when you create it.

**EDIT Add code example:**

```
public class SiteListener implements OnItemClickListener{
    private MyActivity myActivity;

    public SiteListener(MyActivity myActivity) {
        this.myActivity = myActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.site_info, siteInfoFragment)
            .commit();

    }
}
```